# Can my laptop output vga and hdmi simultaneously while running the native display?

Tags: display

I have a Hp 14 bs00x laptop
with i3 7020u and 4gb of ram.
It is running Kubuntu 19.04, I have an external monitor and tv of the same resoluton as the laptop which is 1366 x 768. My laptop has both ports of vga and hdmi so can it run them simultaneously?

Comment: That model is not listed on the HP website, be sure it is correct.

Comment: If that HDMI port is an output port, then most probably yes.

Answer (score 1):

That's kinda hard to say for sure without knowing the exact model of the laptop.

In theory, it should be able to output on all ports (VGA + HDMI + Built-In) simultaneously. The specifications of a reference model ([HP 14-bs001tu](https://support.hp.com/za-en/document/c05527304)) don't list them as exclusive.

However, given that this is a budget laptop, performance might not be satisfactory when using three displays at once.